# Show $\vec x_0 = \vec 0$ or $\vec x_0 \in \mathcal N(A)$ given an ODE system $d\vec x/dt = A \vec x$ and that $A$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The system is given by $$\begin{cases} d\vec x/dt &= A \vec x(t),\\ \vec x(0) &= \vec x_0 \end{cases}$$ I know that the solution is in the form $x(t) = c_1 \vec \eta_1 e^{t \lambda_1} + \dots + c_p \vec \eta_p e^{t \lambda_p}$ or $\vec x_0 e^{t A} = \vec x_0 \Lambda e^{t D} \Lambda^T$, where the eigenspace $\Lambda = [\vec \eta_1 \dots \vec \eta_p]$. This means that $x(0) = c_1 \vec \eta_1 + \dots + c_p \vec \eta_p \in \Lambda$, so clearly $x_0$ can be the zero vector. However, I'm not sure how to continue this fact to show how $\vec x_0$ is in the nullspace of $A$, if $\vec x(t)$ is to remain constant. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $x_0$ a row or a column vector? Consider its position relative to the matrix. Also be aware that you implicitly used $\Lambda^T\Lambda=I$ and $c_k=\eta_k^Tx_0$.

Comment: The expression for $\vec{x}(t)$ should be $\vec{x}(t) = \Lambda e^{t D} \Lambda^T \vec{x}_0 $

Answer (score 1):

Your language is somewhat imprecise:

- $\vec\eta_1,...,\vec\eta_p$ form an *orthonormal* basis for your use of these vectors.
- This is not that strange to demand as the *eigenspaces of a symmetric matrix* are orthogonal, so an orthonormal eigenbasis can always be selected.
- $\Lambda$, the *matrix* with the eigenbasis $[\vec\eta_1,...,\vec\eta_p]$ as columns, is orthogonal (as matrix property), $\Lambda^\top\Lambda = I_p$.
- Any linear combination is in the *span* or *linear hull* of these vectors, the span of any basis covers, by definition, the whole vector space.
- If $\vec x_0$ is not the *zero vector* itself, then at least one of the (Fourier) coefficients $c_k=\vec\eta_k^\top\vec x_0$ is different from zero. This means that not all of the coefficients $c_k e^{\lambda_kt}$ in the linear combination for $x(t)$ are zero. Then $x(t)$ is never zero.

$$
x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^pe^{\lambda_kt} \,\vec \eta_k\vec\eta_k^\top\,\vec x_0=\Lambda e^{tD}\Lambda^\top\vec x_0
$$